# After some tutorials, i tried the scrape the this website.: https://www.usaopps.com/government_contractors/naics-111110-Soybean-Farming.htm

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

This was an attempt to first get the all links from the titles on the first page:
this worked but i want to get the links in a .txt files, and get for all available pages too.

```
bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests
import re

URL= "https://www.usaopps.com/government_contractors/naics-111110-Soybean-Farming.htm"
fixed_url= "https://www.usaopps.com"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(id="contractor-list")

links = []

contractor_elements = results.find_all("div", class_="lr-title")
for contractors_element in contractor_elements:
    
    links = contractors_element.find_all("a")
    for link in links:
        link_url = link["href"]

        
    print(f"full link:{fixed_url}{link_url}\n")
```

after that i got the contact person details and fax number with the code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen


url = "https://www.usaopps.com/government_contractors/contractor-5922555-BSL-GLOBAL-WATER-SOLUTION.htm"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results_info = soup.find(id="box-sideinfo")
info_elements = results_info.find_all("div", class_="info-gen-box clearfix")
Fax = soup.select("#box-sideinfo > div > dl > dd:nth-child(14)")
contact_person = soup.select("#box-sideinfo > div > dl > dd:nth-child(16)")
print(contact_person)
enter code hereprint(Fax)
```

i wanted the new url to be the links from my first code and have the both codes together...

Comment: BS can't parse plain text files. You'll need to write your own code that uses a regular expression to search for links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of obtaining that info, and displaying it in a meaningful way:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

big_list = []
for i in range(1, 2):
    
    url= f"https://www.usaopps.com/government_contractors/naics-111110-Soybean-Farming.{i}.htm"
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    for x in soup.select('div.list-one')[:3]:
        det_url = 'https://www.usaopps.com' + x.select_one('a').get('href')
#         print(det_url)
        req = requests.get(det_url)
        det_soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
        info_box = det_soup.select_one('div.info-gen-box')
        c_name = info_box.find('dt', text='Company Name:').find_next_sibling('dd').text
        c_address = info_box.find('dt', text='Address:').find_next_sibling('dd').text
        c_phone = info_box.find('dt', text='Phone:').find_next_sibling('dd').text
#         print(c_name, c_address, c_phone)
        big_list.append((c_name, c_address, c_phone))

df = pd.DataFrame(big_list, columns = ['Company', 'Address', 'Phone'])
print(df)
```

This will print in terminal:

|  | Company | Address | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | BSL GLOBAL WATER SOLUTIONS, INC | 5020 Campus Dr | 949-296-7666 |
| 1 | JONES 3 CO. LLC | 4133 Fishcreek Rd Apt 401 | 360-279-8638 |
| 2 | Banneker Ventures, LLC | 5 Choke Cherry Road, Suite 378 | 301-990-4980 |

There are 83 pages with companies, so this will take some time.

Requests docs: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
BeautifulSoup docs: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
And of course, pandas docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html

Comment: Thank you so much i will try to carry on from here.

Comment: c_name = info_box.find('dt', text='Contact Person:').find_next_sibling('dd').text
        c_fax = info_box.find('dt', text='Fax:').find_next_sibling('dd').text
        print(c_name, c_fax)
        big_list.append((c_name, c_fax))
            
            



after these changes this error happened.   
 c_fax = info_box.find('dt', text='Fax:').find_next_sibling('dd').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next_sibling'

Comment: some info may be missing for some companies: use try/except blocks for every piece of info.

Comment: with the try it ran and then,
LARRY STOCKER 877-233-4206
WARREN Jones 360-279-8638
Omar A. Karim 301-990-4982
ETHEL M. ROBINSON 770-558-1946
DAISY M COLES 212-402-7736
No fax
THOMAS WILLIAMS 212-402-7736
SUSAN BRITTON 941-484-5856
No fax
Gary Cater 941-484-5856
JOEY SANCHEZ 915-764-2956
GERARD BRANDIMARTE 920-918-9522
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
    c_name = info_box.find('dt', text='Contact Person:').find_next_sibling('dd').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next_sibling'

Comment: c_name = info_box.find('dt', text='Contact Person:').find_next_sibling('dd').text
        try:
            c_fax = info_box.find('dt', text='Fax:').find_next_sibling('dd').text
            
        except AttributeError as error:
            print("No fax")
        finally:
             print(c_name, c_fax)
            
        big_list.append((c_name, c_fax))

Comment: As I said above @LifeUnexplained: you need a try/except block for every piece of info you plan to extract, in case it's missing.